# Reset navigation to another stack navigator in a nested screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have some trouble when I want to reset to another stack navigator then navigate to another screen.

Sub-action of navigate actions inside the reset seems to be not executed. I'm not sure if my understanding of the documentation is bad or if it's a bug.

My reset action looks like that :

```
const resetToScreen2Action = StackActions.reset({
  index: 1,
  key: null,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'numericNavigator' }),
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: 'numericNavigator',
      action: NavigationActions.navigate('screen2'), // not executed ?
    }),
  ],
});
```

I tried a lot of combinations of actions/index… (with React-Navigation 2.3.0 and equivalent with 1.5.11.)

I reproduced that in a snack : https://snack.expo.io/HJrRsYM-X
In the snack example, I want to reset directly to the screen 2, but having the screen 1 on top.

What am I missing ?

**EDIT**: seems to be a bug, I reported an issue https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/4524

Thanks.